# Pass attribute value to view from controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a  tag with the following things:

```
<img src="https://abc.com/abc.png" height="300" width="300">
```

I'm calling a REST API. After calling REST API, I get the values of src, height and width. How can I pass from controller to view in angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

**To controll the src you need to use [ngSrc directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc):**

```
<img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}"/>
```

**To controll the style use [ngStyle directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle):**

```
$scope.myStyle = {"width":"500px", "height":"500px"};

<img ng-style="myStyle"/>
```

Comment: How about height and width?

Comment: I meant height and width for <img> tag

Comment: Want to solve another issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426958/multi-dimensional-array-push-in-angularjs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66671/discussion-between-dang-and-ben-diamant).